# Hiding Grub Menu (Grub 2.02 / Ubuntu 18.10)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, bootloader

I have troubles "deactivating" the Grub boot loader. 
 
Basically I just want to hide it to spare me some time. 
 
Therefore I tried editing the grub file in /etc/default and changed the values according to this page (http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/ubuntu-1404-hide-grub-menu/ or any other page referreing to that matter)

GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0 
 
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true

At the end I also ran `sudo grub-update`. 
Furthermore I tried reinstalling grub ( -pc / -common) completely using apt.
I'm only running Ubuntu so either hiding it or instantly choosing the first option (without it showing) are viable. (GRUB_DEFAULT is already set to 0)

Hopefully somone knows the answer. Thanks in advance!

edit: Current behavior: Grub is not hidden.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 19.04

Edit this file:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Add this line

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER='true'
```

ctrl-x to exit and 'y' to save the file

Then run grub update

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: This solution worked for `Ubuntu 19.10`.